Where is appropriate to ask about O1 experience and process of people who are in academia and science?
would you help me and direct me to right forum about O1 visa.
I know that minimum requirements are 100 citations but I would like to gather experience and impressions of members who went through the process.
Please let me know where is appropriate to ask this question?

Stack Exchange is a place for specific questions and answers.
It's not a good place for open-ended gathering of experiences and impressions.
Specific questions about visas can be on topic at https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic - search first to see if your question has been asked before. But do not ask for impressions and experiences: bring a specific question that you need an answer to.

I’ll just add that chat would also be appropriate here — this stack’s main room is the Ivory Tower. Though traffic there has been quite low lately.

Ok maybe I worded wrongly but I was about to ask for academic part of application @Bryan Krause. Not about overall impression. Just about bureaucracy

@looktook What would the title/one sentence version of your question be?

@BryanKrause What evidence from academic achievements strengthens an O-1 visa petition?

How can early-career academics demonstrate "extraordinary ability" for an O-1 visa?

How should academics document "original contributions of major significance" for an O-1 visa?

Is serving as a reviewer for academic journals strong evidence for an O-1 visa petition?

Does leading a research project qualify as "a critical role" for an O-1 visa?

@cag51 what is ivory tower?

@looktook: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2496/the-ivory-tower

@cag51 ok, i posted there, but i look like some sort of metachat with links

It is our regular chatroom, can be used for most purposes. Though like I said, it has not had much traffic lately, so you may or may not get a reply.

@cag51 can you take a look at my potential question

@looktook: I don't have much to add to what Bryan wrote. Your potential question asks to "gather experience and impressions of members who went through the process," which is not what we do here. We are a Q&A site. You could try to recast it as a question, but even then, it's a very specific question, so it'll be hard to find people who are qualified to answer it. Reddit would probably accept the question in its current form, but no idea if you'll find a qualified answerer over there or which subreddit to use. Sorry I can't be more helpful.

@cag51 NO! Take a look at all questions I proposed. Read above
